# PHP: build an associative array from list without replacing values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I have this list in a file:

```
paul,1
peter,1
mary,1
ian,1
paul,2
peter,2
mary,2
paul,3
mary,3
```

I have to end up with an array like this:

```
$people=array(
    'paul'=>array(1,2,3),
    'peter'=>array(1,2),
    'mary'=>array(1,2,3),
    'ian'=>array(1)
);
```

Here is where I am:

```
$a=file($f);//$a=array, $f=file
foreach($a as $b){
    $l=explode(',',$b);//$l=list
    $p=$l[0];//$p=person
    $n=$l[1];//$n=number
}
print_r($lista);
```

But it is not working, of course. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What are `$e` and `$d` in your code sample?

Comment: Just garbage, sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there, but you have to check your variable names. E.g. `$d` and `$e` are not defined anywhere and you are passing the wrong argument to `in_array`.

This should do it:

```
$file = file($f);
$list = array();

foreach($file as $line){
    list($name, $value) = explode(',', $line);
    if(!isset($list[$name])) {
        $list[$name] = array();
    }
    $list[$name][] = $value;
}

print_r($list);
```

Comment: Why `isset()` instead of [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)?

Comment: Because I wanted to type less ;) It's equivalent in this case. If a possible array value is `null`, then one has to use `array_key_exists`, otherwise `isset` is fine as well.

Comment: This line has the entire answer: `$list[$name][] = $value;`

Comment: @Roger: Well, `array_push($lista[$name],$value)` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *requirement* to check that an array already exists, or not, for the current name. PHP will, given the syntax below, happily create the array for a name if it does not already exist.

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
    list($name, $number) = explode(',', $b);
    $lista[$name][] = $number;
}
```

Comment: The syntax can actually handle it, but humans sometimes cannot. You can end up having values from a previous use in the array or get items injected to the array through `register_globals`. I recommend to initiate each array with `$var = array()` just to be safe.

Comment: I guess learning the language is sometimes too much to ask. Whoops.

Comment: It is not about knowing the language or not. In some cases it is a serious security issue. And this is always underestimated at least untill somebody exploit it on your website.

Comment: In some cases, sure it is an issue. In this case, it is not. Please don't bother making further tangential comments, I may be impolite and not respond.

Comment: I am sorry if I'd hit you personally. It wasn't intended. But to me security means a lot and any injection is a bad one. MySQL injections being the most popular ones I think. You stated it is never necessary and my heart had to point out the danger. I apologize for that.

Comment: Correction: I said there is "no *requirement* to check that an array already exists". The answer simply shows that initialising the sub-array each time is not *required*. I never **ever** said "[security is] never necessary".  Please, I'm all for teaching folks about writing solid code but spewing your precious tidbits of knowledge by commenting on this answer is **not** the appropriate time, place or method to do that teaching.